# Create Record (CObject) from OpportunityLineItem when Opportunity is Closed Won

Tags: custom-object, opportunity

I'm trying to create a record of each item in the Opportunity when an Opportunity is Closed Won.

OpportunityItemList:

- Date   (Date)
- Product2   Lookup(Product)
- ExpiryDate__c   (Date)
- ServiceNumber__c   Text(30)
- Opportunity   Lookup(Opportunity)

Membership__c

- AccountName__c   Lookup(Account)
- ExpiryDate__c   (Date)
- IssuedDate__c   (Date)
- OpportunityName__c   Lookup(Opportunity)
- ServiceName__c   Lookup(Product)

I'm using this trigger but I get blank info in the Lookup fields...

```
trigger CreateMembership on OpportunityLineItem (after update) {

    List<Membership__c> comms = new List<Membership__c>(); 

    for(OpportunityLineItem a : trigger.new) {   

            Membership__c comm = new Membership__c();

            comm.Name = a.ServiceNumber__c; 

            comm.AccountName__c = a.Opportunity.AccountId; 
            comm.OpportunityName__c = a.OpportunityId; 
            comm.ServiceName__c = a.PricebookEntry.Product2Id;  

            comm.Stage__c = 'Active'; 
            comm.IssuedDate__c = a.ServiceDate;
            comm.ExpiryDate__c = a.ExpiryDate__c;

            comms.add(comm);    

    }

    insert comms; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a trigger, only the immediate fields of the object are populated. To get values from other objects you have to run your own query, and using [relationship queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) of some form usually works best.

In this case its probably simplest to just query for all the fields, but in other circumstances a mixture of the queried and Trigger.new values might make more sense:

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = [
        select ServiceNumber__c, Opportunity.AccountId, OpportunityId,
                PricebookEntry.Product2Id, ServiceDate, ExpiryDate__c
        from OpportunityLineItem
        where Id in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()
        ];
for (OpportunityLineItem a : lineItems) {
     // Same code here
}
```

Comment: Keith, how I know if the Opportunity is Won or Lost? Can I do that in the same query? Can I verify first if the Membership already exist if not Create it?

Comment: As there may be other reasons that the OpportunityLineItem is updated you should check for specific changes (by comparing values in Trigger.new vs Trigger.old) and then only do the query in my answer if necessary. And yes either create the Membership__c once only (you'll have to query to see if any are already there) or perhaps better update/upsert it to make sure the values are current. So your trigger is going to get quite a bit longer.